# rearrange the UIButton position in a UIView iphone?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, position

i have a set of UIButtons in my class. according to the url fields from UIWebView i need to rearrange the position of my buttons.

my button array is

```
 buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6, nil];
```

these buttons are arranged in order, if mu url field gives the value false means i need to remove the button btn1 and other buttons should the retain the display order.

i tried this code

```
if(false)
   {
   btn1.hidden=YES;
   btn2.center=CGPointMake(btn1.frame.origin.x, btn1.frame.origin.y);

   }
```

but the btn2 does not take the position of btn1.

how will i arrange my buttons such that other buttons should retain the display order even when some of the buttons are missing in display.

hope will get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at an accessible computer but just a guess...Try:

```
CGRect buttonFrame = btn1.frame;
[btn2 setFrame: buttonFrame];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//please set first btn1 position 

btn1.hidden=YES;
btn2.frame=CGPointMake(btn1.frame.origin.x, btn1.frame.origin.y);
```

Comment: i created the buttons in nib file , all buttons are arranged

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
   btn1.hidden=YES;
   btn2.center=CGPointMake(btn1.frame.origin.x, btn1.frame.origin.y);
```

use the center of btn2

```
   btn1.hidden=YES;
   btn2.center= btn1.center;
```